# Ruby | Kernel#load wrap module

Tags: ruby

The [Kernel#load](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.1.2/Kernel.html#method-i-load) method loads and executes a program from the specified file. This method has the second parameter which can be set as a module. In this case *“the loaded script will be executed under the given module”*.

Could you provide any examples of this usage and explain when it can be useful and why?

Answer (score 1):

An excerpt from the documentation

> If the optional wrap parameter is true, the loaded script will be executed under an anonymous module, protecting the calling program's global namespace.

Meaning if the script defines any methods, or constants (also modules/classes), then they won't affect your environment where you call it from.

`loaded.rb`

```
def foo
  puts 'in loaded'
end

foo
```

main program

```
def foo
  puts 'in main program'
end

foo # 'in main program'
load 'loaded.rb' # will output 'in loaded'
foo # 'in loaded
```

The foo method was overridden by the load. If you want to avoid that, set the 2nd parameter to true.

```
def foo
  puts 'in main program'
end

foo # 'in main program'
load 'loaded.rb', true # will output 'in loaded'
foo # 'in main program'
```

The other option for the 2nd argument introduced recently in ruby 3.1 is to give it a module. The loaded code will then run in the context of that module.

It can be used for example to give a set of methods for the loaded script that it expects without defining them on the global scope.

`loaded.rb`

```
puts foo
```

main program

```
load 'loaded.rb' # NameError
```

You can define the method it needs globally

```
def foo = 'baz'
load 'loaded.rb' # 'baz'
```

But then the method is defined globally which you might not want.
Alternatively you can define it in a module.

```
module Bar
  def foo = 'baz'
end

load 'loaded.rb' # NameError
load 'loaded.rb', true #  NameError
load 'loaded.rb', Bar, # 'baz'
```

Comment: My question wasn't about the anonymous module, but the user specified module as a wrap argument. That way you can provide a top-level module for the loaded script. I need a usage example and an explanation about what problems this feature designed to solve. I'm talking about [this](https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/6210) feature request. I need more clarification on the topic.

Comment: Edited to answer to also address that.